# How do I create multiple dataframes using a loop by separating an existing dataframe by a variable

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I have data that is like the following (Except that is populated by all 52 weeks). "data"

```
Week   State    Value 
1        CA      4
1        AL      5
1        MO      9
1        IL      12
2        NY      1
2        CA      2
2        WA      8
3        WY      9
3        SC      10
```

I would like to create new data.frames for every week so that I may do further analyses. How would I go about this? I tried:

```
for( i in 1:52) {
     DataWeeki <- data[which(data$Week==i),]
}
```

This creates a single dataframe of 3 variables (with the appropriate variable names) but no data.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split` in `base R` to create a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
lst1 <- split(data, data$Week)
names(lst1) <- paste0("DataWeek", 1:52)
```

From the list, elements can be extracted with `$` or `[[`

```
lst1[["DataWeek1"]]
```

It is not recommended to create multiple objects in the global environment, but if we need, we can use `list2env` (but there would be 52 objects and not good at all)

```
 list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Regarding why it creates a single object is because the object gets updated in each run and what we get is the last run object.  Instead, here `assign` is needed (not recommended)

```
for( i in 1:52) {
   assign(paste0("DataWeek", i), data[which(data$Week==i),])
 }
```

`list`s can also be created with `for` loop

```
lst1 <- vector("list", 52)
for(i in 1:52) {
       lst1[[i]] <- data[which(data$Week==i),]
  }
```

Comment: Great! This worked. Thank you! However, all of these new dataframes created are named 1,2,3 etc. Can I have control in naming these somehow besides doing it manually?

Comment: @LucasWalz  If you check my update `names(lst1) <- paste0("DataWeek", 1:52)`